# Train test split mysql records into views

Tags: mysql, train-test-split

how do i create two views, one for training data and the other for test data 70:30 split in mySql.

```
CREATE VIEW training_data
AS
SELECT Posts.post_content as post_content,
    CASE 
        WHEN (Posts.post_title like '%covid%corona%covid19%' or Posts.post_content like '%covid%corona%covid19%') THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END AS tag 
FROM Posts;

CREATE VIEW test_data
AS
SELECT Posts.post_content as post_content,
    CASE 
        WHEN (Posts.post_title like '%covid%corona%covid19%' or Posts.post_content like '%covid%corona%covid19%') THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END AS tag 
FROM Posts;
```

Comment: Enumerate (ROW_NUMBER function) while sorting by some unique expression then select based of this number and an expression which provides needed relation.

Comment: Can you please help me out with an example, i'm very new to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW training_data
AS
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Posts.post_content as post_content,
                     CASE WHEN Posts.post_title like '%covid%corona%covid19%'
                          THEN 1
                          WHEN Posts.post_content like '%covid%corona%covid19%' 
                          THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 END AS tag,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
              FROM Posts )
SELECT post_content, tag
FROM cte
WHERE rn MOD 10 IN (0,1,3,4,6,7,9);
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW test_data
AS
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Posts.post_content as post_content,
                     CASE WHEN Posts.post_title like '%covid%corona%covid19%'
                          THEN 1
                          WHEN Posts.post_content like '%covid%corona%covid19%' 
                          THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 END AS tag,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
              FROM Posts )
SELECT post_content, tag
FROM cte
WHERE rn MOD 10 IN (2,5,8);
```

Take into account - both queries are slow due to fullscan. I'd recommend you to add generated column with `tag` expression into the table structure for to improve.